# Find String In Dictionary

Tags: swift, dictionary

I have the following dictionary:

```
[(key: "name", value: G. Snyder), (key: "1", value: 00:01:01), (key: "2", value: 00:02:02)]
```

I need to search the dictionary and find the index of where the key:"name" exists and delete the pair. How would I go about doing this?

I am struggling because it is a `sortedArray: [(key: String, value: Any)]`, not a regular dictionary like I am used to.

Thanks

Comment: dictionary is invalid with dots in value

Comment: @ÖzgürErsil so I need to remove the dot after the G.? Can I not just search for a key value of "name" get that index then remove it?

Comment: Why don’t you just remove that from the original dictionary?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't have a dictionary. As you said, you have an array of tuples. Removing an element from an array of tuples is done with `filter`.

```
newArray = oldArray.filter { $0.key != "name" }
```

You can also, as you note "search for a key value of "name" get that index then remove it." (Since you knew this answer, it's unclear what your question is.)

```
if let index = array.index(where: { $0.key == "name" }) {
    array.remove(at: index)
}
```

Comment: Ahh thanks. I will do some more research on tuples to get a better understanding. Thank you for your help

Comment: Adding a note for future readers, just in case someone stumbles in here months for now and fails to understand OP:s special context (array of tuples with unique "key" named tuple member entries): the `filter` approach above will removed _all_ tuples from `oldArray` for which the predicate fails, i.e., all tuple values where the named tuple member `key` equals `"name"`. For the `index(where:)` approach, however, only the _first_ such member will be removed (even if there are several: not the case for OP's example).